# Moment.format() modifies times according to timezone

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am using Moment.js to represent data coming from backend. In my case I have a date
represented in this format "2015-01-02T00:00:00Z". Then I feed it to Moment.Format()

```
moment("2015-01-02T00:00:00Z").format('LLL')
```

what comes out of this is "01/01/2015" , which is a different date.
To give more details, we are facing such bug when the timezone of the computer is set to something else.
So, if I am where I am now, let's say Rome and the timezone is set correctly here, moment.Format() returns the right date "02/01/2015". If instead I change the timezone in the system of my computer and for example I put Lima, then it goes to "01/01/2015". How do I make sure the right date is shown without depending on the timezone?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I understand, do you mean you want to always show the date in UTC (i.e. the way the string shows it)? If so, it's just `moment.utc("2015-01-02T00:00:00Z").format('LLL')`.

Comment: Rome is east of 0° longitude (the datum for UTC) and is 2 hours ahead of UTC, so 2015-01-02T00:00:00Z (i.e. UTC) is 2015-01-02T02:00:00+02:00 local time in Rome, so the same date. Lima is west of 0° at GMT -5, so it's not yet 2 January and the local date is 2015-01-01T19:00:00-05:00. They are all the same instant in time, just with different offsets from UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy.... here we go again with dates :O

Ok so starting off, take a look at this sentence that you wrote

> How do I make sure the right date is shown without depending on the
>   timezone?

And now I raise you this question:

> A greek guy ( me ) wants to date you. I wanna take you to dinner, lets
>   say this Monday 2019/09/23 20:00:00

Now because I told you that I am greek you can infer by the difference in our time zones that my "Monday 2019/09/23 20:00:00" is actually your "Monday 2019/09/23 12:00:00". And you can show up on time, all though my dinner is actually your lunch.

I hope you get my point from this, now onto your case:

You will either:

1. Only support people's date when they originate from the same time zone as your developing team ( not cool for a project, but many times a company has no need to communicate dates with people from other timezones)
2. You will have to provide the TimeZone that your date was "constructed with" to moment, so it can resolve the differences to the local time of each user.
3. You will convert all dates to UTC, so the server will only "speak" UTC times, while the clients will the be free to convert to their needed time zone. You wont have to provide the "original timezone" because of the convention that your dates are always UTC (which implies the "original timezone" actually to 0 )

I hope the above helps to get you some basic understanding of the dates issue.

Comment: I would wait for you at the estabilished time from lunch to dinner :P

No I understand what you mean. Thing is, the date is already registered in the UTC way. I go more into detail. What happens in my scenario is that someone (person A) reports "something" happened at a certain time. This time gets saved in the database in UTC way. Now I want to show this time to someone else (person B). Problem is that if the person B is in another timezone, the Moment.Format() will take that into account and shift the time accordingly, which I don't want to.

Comment: as @Daniel commented above, **moment.utc("2015-01-02T00:00:00Z").format('LLL')** was the solution.. but I would still come for a date due to your kind explanation :) thank you!